# Tests are OK with mvn test, but fails in mvn package

Tags: maven, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, junit5, java-10

We have a JUnit 5 test in a Spring Boot project testing the response from a controller that creates a Protobuf output. If I execute the test suite from within an IDE (both Eclipse and IntelliJ are used in the team) as JUnit tests, all pass. If I run `mvn test` from a terminal they also pass. BUT, if execute `mvn package` this test fails.

I can't figure out what the difference is here, the test phase should be the same in `test`and `package`? Is this related to how we depend on Jupiter somehow?

When the test fails it will end up with a 406 response instead of the expected 200. This is is the same behavior as when a `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` is not registered in the context. This puzzles me though, the test runs perfect in the test phase so why not when package is executed?

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
  ...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the output when the test fails:

```bash
Async:
Async started = false
 Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
         Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

 ModelAndView:
     View name = null
          View = null
         Model = null 

 FlashMap:
    Attributes = null

 MockHttpServletResponse:
        Status = 406
 Error message = null
       Headers = {}
  Content type = null
          Body = 
 Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
       Cookies = []
```

Comment: First I would suggest to use the most recent version of JUnit 5 furthermore only define a dependency to jupiter-engine and no deps for the plugin and no deps to launcher...[already handled by surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html).

Comment: No, stay on 5.2.0 of "JUnit" for now. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1564 for details.
The remainder of @khmarbaise comment should make it work.

Comment: Actually, it has been a bug in Eclipse/Maven integration that led us to set deps in the plugin section. But this got me digging in the poms and found the reason within the plugins, it seems there was a dependency version conflict that caused the generated-sources folder not to be found. I refactored the pom-files for the project and it seems that the error disappeared.